# How to configure MVC on a Blazor WebAssembly Hosted Solution

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, blazor

I have a Blazor WebAssembly Hosted solution (Client and Server) setup with IdentityServer for Authentication.  I am looking to do 2 things...

1. I would like to set up MVC on the Server since I am more comfortable with MVC.  The idea for Server Side pages would be for things like Profile Management and accessing Content that I do not want to on the Client.

The Server Startup.cs currently has

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            ....Condensed

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();
        }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, DataContext dataContext)
        {
           .....Condensed

           app.UseRouting();

            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
            });
        }
```

2. With MVC setup on the backend, how can I navigate to these pages from the Client?

Comment: Usually when I want to add a framework to an application, I use VS or the command line to create a new empty application of the type I want. Then I examine the configuration it automatically generated, and piece by piece copy the relevant configuration into my existing application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create your WebAssembly solution, be sure to check the box "ASP.Net Core Hosted".

This will create three projects: Client, Shared, and Server.

In the server project you will find a Controllers folder.  Go ahead and add a controller, such as DummyController.cs

```
namespace BlazorWASM4.Server.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class DummyController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Then right-click on your controller method Index and click 'Add View'.  Then implement the view (Index.cshtml) like this for example:

```
<h1>Dummy Page</h1>
```

Run the project and navigate to localhost:port/Dummy

You should see your new page get displayed.

Comment: I did that and it went into the Blazor routing and said the page could not be found.  Thats ultimately why i asked the question here because i thought it should work just as you posted.  I was wondering if i needed to change anything within the app.UseEndpoints

Comment: I notice though you do have it marked as an APIController.  I did not have it marked as an APIController.  I will try that and see

Comment: @JoeyD, my code for app.UseEndPoints is identical to what you posted in your question